# Calculate radius r = x^2 + y^2 using array values

Tags: arrays, numpy, calculation

I would like to use my calculated y[0] (x-values) and y[1] (y-values) from sol_3 using the solve_ivp to find the radius(r) and plot r(t).
How can I calculate r using x and y values from sol_r? I keep getting TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.
It seems like I am having issues with data type.

Please find my code below:

```
timing = np.array([0,2*math.pi]) #t0 = 0 tf=2pi
sol_3 = solve_ivp(fun = motion, t_span=[-math.pi, 2*math.pi], y0 = initial, method='RK23')
x = (sol_3.y[0, :])
y = (sol_3.y[1, :])

r = math.sqrt(sol_3.y[1,:]**2+sol_3.y[0,:]**2)


The array of the sol_3 looks like this:
message: 'The solver successfully reached the end of the integration interval.'
     nfev: 599
     njev: 0
      nlu: 0
      sol: None
   status: 0
  success: True
        t: array([-3.14159265, -3.14155739, -3.14120473, -3.13767817, -3.12223578,
       -3.09595606, -3.0602884 , -3.01493539, -2.96220999, -2.90868487,
       -2.86527118, -2.82204945, -2.76814683, -2.69499434, -2.61108567,
       -2.51943819, -2.44000487, -2.36057156, -2.28852194, -2.20054302,
       -2.10648128, -2.03001656, -1.97695204, -1.92388751, -1.87465566,
       -1.82156056, -1.76673945, -1.73011416, -1.70585555, -1.68159695,
       -1.64979671, -1.60847127, -1.55783888, -1.50388809, -1.45063319,
       -1.40126952, -1.3488944 , -1.27797028, -1.19501887, -1.1039372 ,
       -1.02086808, -0.95113058, -0.88636741, -0.80259334, -0.70932861,
       -0.61584263, -0.55777683, -0.50936554, -0.46344206, -0.4113168 ,
       -0.35663683, -0.31427459, -0.28317047, -0.25206634, -0.22135512,
       -0.18102468, -0.13108896, -0.07689042, -0.02318517,  0.02738243,
        0.07818198,  0.14701599,  0.22918967,  0.31978884,  0.41431515,
        0.48493772,  0.55000025,  0.63412425,  0.72775963,  0.82162403,
        0.87984573,  0.92849841,  0.97470164,  1.02711062,  1.0820909 ,
        1.12462382,  1.15583674,  1.18704967,  1.21796912,  1.25856295,
        1.30880593,  1.36330716,  1.41729713,  1.46809564,  1.51919004,
        1.58841181,  1.67102044,  1.76206092,  1.85696013,  1.92801041,
```

Comment: exactly on which part of code do you get "too many values to unpack"? second thing, could you make [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Its for the r = math.sqrt(sol_3.y[1,:]**2+sol_3.y[0,:]**2)